# string_char_traits<char> in C++11 for GNU/G++ 4.9 (earlier 2.95.3)

Tags: c++, string, c++11, g++, g++4.9

I have some legacy C++ code (used to compile using GNU g++ 2.95.3) having the following declaration  `std::basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,malloc_alloc> x;`
The header file was

```
#include <std/bastring.h>
```

Now, I am migrating to GU g++ 4.9 where I'm getting this error:
1. `std/bastring.h` not found
2. When I change #include `<std/bastring.h>` as `#include <string>`, I'm getting the following error:

```
error: 'string_char_traits' was not declared in this scope
std::basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,malloc_alloc> x;
error: template argument 2 is invalid
std::basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,malloc_alloc> x;
error: expected unqualified-id before ',' token
std::basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,malloc_alloc> x;
                                              ^
```

Need guidance / help to make this compilable under GNU g++ 4.9

Comment: Do you know why `malloc_alloc` was used in the first place rather than just `alloc`? You might be able to get away with just using `std::string`.

Comment: @DieterLücking fatal error: std/bastring: No such file or directory

Comment: @TartanLlama I'm not sure why malloc_alloc was used instead of alloc, are you syaing std::string would do same as std::basic_string?

Comment: `std::string` is just a typedef for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`, so as long as the default allocator fits your needs, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the publication of ISO/IEC 14882:1998, GCC 2.95.3 is very much not a C++98 conforming compiler. We're talking about a 15 year old compiler running on the coattails of god awful who-knows-what non-standard code from the '90s. For one thing, here's a snippet from `bastring.h`:

```
// Written by Jason Merrill based upon the specification by Takanori Adachi
// in ANSI X3J16/94-0013R2.

...

// NOTE : This does NOT conform to the draft standard and is likely to change
#include <alloc.h>
```

I don't know what `ANSI X3J16/94-0013R2` but it definitely has nothing to do with ISO C++98. `malloc_alloc` is found in  `alloc.h`, if for some reason you want to explicitly want `malloc` and `free` to to be used in the allocator.

Anyways, your codebase is no doubt going to have to be rewritten from scratch. `std::basic_string<char,string_char_traits<char>,malloc_alloc> x;` can be replaced with `std::string`. But I shudder at the horrors of what other pre-standard code lies in there.

Comment: ANSI X3J16/94-0013R2 is a C++ committee paper from, well, 1994. (ANSI X3J16 is the U.S. C++ committee.) Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be available online.